# How to skip /dev/sda1: clean in booting system?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

When I start system I see black display with message:

```
/dev/sda1: clean....blocks
```

How to skip this step and run Ubuntu? It takes over 3 hours to check HDD 500 gb

Comment: Or I must to wait finishing?

Comment: In my case it was due to ***gdm3*** not running. So I restarted it using these commands:
```
sudo service gdm3 status (to ckeck status)
sudo service gdm3 start
```
It doesn't matter if you are using lightgdm, gdm or gdm. To find out which one you are using try `sudo service --status-all | grep gdm`

Comment: THE SOLUTION IS HERE https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NOTE: Your question is off-topic for this site. It should be on Ask Ubuntu. But to make things easier, I will answer it here.

Use your favorite text editor to open `/etc/fstab` (WARNING: Be very careful when editing this file. It controls how your system mounts filesystems on boot).

Find the line for `/dev/sda1` At the end of the line, you should see a 1, or 2. Change this to a `0`. This tells the system to not run `fsck` whenever it boots.

Comment: I can not enter in system that to edit config, your answer is ot actual

Comment: @Daniel Please clarify that?

Comment: @Daniel If you cannot access the system, try running a live DVD or USB, mounting the filesystem on /dev/sda1, and repeat the steps, except prefixing `/etc/` with the mountpoint.

Comment: @Daniel Did that work for you?

Comment: I have the same problem but this didn't solve it.

Comment: This is shooting yourself in the foot. I highly recommend to NOT do this. `fsck` checks your root partition on every boot for a reason. Yes, the message is mild discomfort but I speak from experience when I say, it saved me hours of gluing my finger to the Y key on the keyboard. There's gotta be a better way than to disable it alltogether!

Comment: He said it took 3 hours

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> or <kbd>f3</kbd>
- login with your account
- type `sudo apt-get update` (enter password when prompted)
- type `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel`
- reboot

Comment: When do you start this? When in GUI, right? What do those things do?